# What is an sensible default for a the hostname of a SMTP server?

Tags: smtp, default, hostname

A SMTP server should include its fully qualified domain name in the greeting message. What would be a sensible default if none is specified in the configuration?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to read the hostname/domainname from the running system.

For example in C you could use gethostname().